# How can I view the map in Assassin's Creed III?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Ok, this is a total newb question, but can't figure it out. I'm playing AC3 on a PC with an XBOX 360 controller connected. How can I open the map? Or, can I open the map? I have this tiny minimap in the corner of course, but I'd like to see more of the map.

Or can't I open the map until later? I'm almost done with sequence 5.

Comment: I don't have AC3 yet, but in the other games you could typically open it with a button or you could open it from the pause menu.  I played on 360/PS3, not PC so sorry I can't be of more help.  Check the settings and the button configuration perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I tried checking the settings but for some reason it doesn't seem to say anything about button configuration at all.

Comment: Ah damn, I overlooked that you were playing with a 360 controller, could have answered hah.  Oh well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, in all the AC games, the back button (just above the 4-directional button) is used to open the map.

For PC: Tab typically opens the map; for PS3, press Select.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Has been crazy annoying since the game kept hinting at "open the map to do x". Didn't notice that button at all. First time gamepad user here :p

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this option to include how to open it from all 4 platforms the game is available on: PC, Xbox 360, PS3, Wii U. That way this question isn't so localized to the Xbox. You can open the map by pressing the Select button on a PS3 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if you can open the map  with the "Back" button or press the start button and go to map, if that doesn't work look at the AcIII guide

Hope this helped :P

Answer (score 0):

Press the "select" button.

I just figured it out after searching the internet, I own the game and had difficulty finding it too.