# how do I view the map not the mini map in assassins creed III on ps3

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-3

I have been trying to figure this out forever I'm starting to think the might not be one

Comment: Try taking a look here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-can-i-view-the-map-in-assassins-creed-iii

Answer (score 0):

The map can be displayed by pressing the `Select` button (PS3), the `Back` button (360) or the `Tab` key (PC - default).

The map is only accessible within the Animus. You can access it during the tutorial already, although at that point, there is no map data available, thus making this feature useless until later in the game.